# Where is the ntpd package on Ubuntu Wily (15.10)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntp, ntpd

I am looking for/trying to install ntpd

I am using the following Ubuntu distribution:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

sudo apt-get install ntpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ntpd
```

What I do see is the openntpd - OpenBSD NTP daemon package.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Ubuntu webpage [Time Synchronisation with NTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html):

> sudo apt install ntp

The [manpage for `ntpd.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/ntpd.conf.5.html) says

> wily (5) ntpd.conf.5.gz
>   Provided by: openntpd_5.7p3_1_i386

and following that link: [OpenBSD NTP daemon](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+package/openntpd) says

> This is an alternative implementation of the NTP software, made by the OpenBSD
>    Project. It makes use of privilege separation, only implements a subset of the
>    NTP protocol, adjusting the rate of the clock to synchronize the local clock.
>   Alternative packages which provide similar functionality are **`ntp`** and **`chrony`**.

So according to the description, you could use any of those (at least there are packages for [`ntp`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+package/ntp) and [`crony`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/chrony)).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I installed ntp and I am poking around to examine the time broadcast frequency

Your answer should also be sudo apt-get install ntp

Answer (score 1):

In [Ubuntu's repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/ntp), it is called `ntp`.

`sudo apt-get install ntp`